# Numpy check where elements of two arrays are approximately equal

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays with floating point values and I am trying to find the indices where the numbers are approximately equal (floating point comparisons).

So something like:

```
x = np.random.rand(3)
y = np.random.rand(3)

x[2] = y[2]

# Do the comparison and it should return 2 as the index
```

I tried something like

```
np.where(np.allclose(x, y))
```

However, this returns an empty array. If I do:

```
np.where(x == y)  # This is fine.
```

I tried using a combination of `numpy.where` and `numpy.allclose` but could not make it work. Of course, I can do it with a loop but that seems tedious and unpythonic.

Comment: Try `np.isclose` instead of `np.allclose`?

Comment: Of course! What a brain freeze. If you write this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you look for is [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
np.where(np.isclose(x, y))
```

Comment: I am waiting for 10 minutes to pass. You guys are too fast and sharp!

Answer (score 5):

You can always use something relying on:

```
np.where( np.abs(x-y) < epsilon )
```